# Angularjs best practice for specific domain for certain assets

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to know what’s the best practice to have a domain set as a variable for some of my videos.

Let’s say all my videos are stored on a certain domain. How do I set this so in the future if the domain changes but the file is the same I can only update the domain I one place.

`<a href=http://domainthatmaychangelater.com/videos/ namewillneverchange.mp4”>videos</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use a constant value, and inject it where needed.

```
var angularApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

angularApp.value("videoDomain", "http://domainthatmaychangelater.com/videos/");

angularApp.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);
MyCtrl.$inject = ["videoDomain"];
function MyCtrl(videoDomain) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.videoDomain = videoDomain;
}
```

Template:

```
<a ng-href="{{$ctrl.videoDomain}}namewillneverchange.mp4">videos</a>
```